# Rails: generate a full URL in an ActionMailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer to send a sign up confirmation email. The email needs to contain a link back to the site to verify the user, but I can't persuade Rails to generate a full URL (including the domain etc).

I'm using:

```
<%= url_for :controller => 'login', :action => 'verify', :guid => @user.new_user.guid, :only_path => false, :host => 'http://plantality.com' %>
```

in my view

### Part b:

In development mode Rails gripes if I don't specify the host explicilty in the link above. But I don't want to do this in production. Any solutions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To solve the problem to pass a host for generating URLs in ActionMailer, check out [this plugin](http://github.com/weppos/actionmailer_with_request) and the [reason why I wrote it](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/10/actionmailer-and-host-value/).

To solve the first issue, use named routes when applicable. Instead of

```
<%= url_for :controller => 'login', :action => 'verify', :guid => @user.new_user.guid, :only_path => false, :host => 'http://plantality.com' %>
```

assuming the route is called `login`, use

```
<%= login_url(:guid => @user.new_user.guid) %>
```

Note, I'm using `login_url`, not `login_path`.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if it is what you want but in config/environments/development.rb you can specify default options for mailer urls

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => "your.host.org",
  :port => 3000
}
```

you can do the same in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: I'm using syntax that you've provided without :host part, and I'm getting full URLs. :only_path => false is important.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why the previous solutions seem so complicated, but since I'm here why not give my 2 cents...

Go to `/config/environments` and add:

`config.absolute_site_url = 'your site url'`

for the respective environment (ie. in development.rb, test.rb, or production.rb).  Restart web server.

This allows you to call `Rails.application.config.absolute_site_url` to get the desired URL. No need for plugins or weird cheat, just store the site url as an application wide variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not 100% correct way but this can also be a solution :

See the **Using asset hosts** section in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html). You need to specify an `asset_host`. You can also construct it dynamically from the request chaining `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/login/?guid=#{@user.new_user.guid}"`

Comment: `request` exists in an action mailer view? what if is a background job?

Answer (score -1):

To generate url, try this

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_url(User.first.id, host: 'yourhost.io')
```

this will generate url like this:

> http://yourhost.io/users/1

As well you can pass some params

```
expires = Time.now + 2.days
params = {expires: expires}
u = User.first.id

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_url(u, params, host: 'host.com')
```

will generate:

> http://yourhost.io/users/1.expires=2018-08-12+15%253A52%253A15+%252B0300

so you can werifi in action if link is not expired